# How to implement a superoptimizer

Tags: performance, algorithm, logic

[Related to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12664/implement-superoptimizer-for-addition from Sep 27, 2013]

I am interested in how to write [superoptimizers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoptimization). In particular to find small logical formulae for sums of bits.  This was previously set this as a challenge on codegolf but it seems a lot harder than one might imagine.

I would like to write code that finds the smallest possible propositional logical formula to check if the sum of y binary 0/1 variables equals some value x.  Let us call the variables x1, x2, x3, x4 etc.  In the simplest approach the logical formula should be  equivalent to the sum. That is, the logical formula should be true if and only if the sum equals x.

Here is a naive way to do that.  Say y=15 and x = 5. Pick all 3003 different ways of choosing 5 variables and for each make a new clause with the AND of those variables AND the AND of the negation of the remaining variables. You end up with 3003 clauses each of length exactly 15 for a total cost of 45054.

However, if you are allowed to introduce new variables into your solution then you can potentially reduce this a lot by eliminating common subformulae. So in this case your logical formula consists of the y binary variables, x and some new variables.  The whole formula would be satisfiable if and only if the sum of the y variables equals x.   The only allowed operators are `and`, `or` and `not`.

It turns out there is a [clever method](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wklieber/papers/2007_efficient-cnf-encoding-for-selecting-1.pdf) for solving this problem when  x =1, at least in theory .  However, I am looking for a computational intensive method to search for small solutions.

```
How can you make a superoptimizer for this problem?
```

Examples.  Take as an example two variables where we want a logical formula that is True exactly when they sum to 1.  One possible answer is:

```
(((not y0) and (y1)) or ((y0) and (not y1)))
```

To introduce a new variable into a formula  such as `z0` to represent `y0 and not y1` then we can introduce a new clause  `(y0 and  not y1) or not z0` and replace `y0 and not y1` by `z0` throughout the rest of the formula .  Of course this is pointless in this example as it makes the expression longer.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here.  Please provide some examples of the derived propositional logic formulas that you are talking about and that match your example constraints.  Please clarify why you say "*..the sum of y binary 0/1 variables..*", then "..*Say y=15 and x = 5. Pick all 3003 different ways of choosing 5 variables*..", why is `y`(15) the number of variables and then its `x`(5)?  And how do you get 3003 combinations from variables?  You're missing a lot of explanation because what's here really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, as you are asking for code: Please show us what you already have.

Comment: @RBarryYoung  15 choose 5 is 3003. This is the number of different way of choosing which 5 of the 15 variables should be set to 1. The other 10 will then be set to 0.  So there are 3003 different ways of getting exactly 5 and each way has 15 variables in it.  The linked question has some example code and outputs. I didn't want to copy someone else's code.

Comment: Per the FAQ: "What have you tried and why didn't it work?"

Comment: @RBarryYoung I tried the method I described which makes huge formulae. I don't know how to make a superoptimizer that searches for small formulae. I added some examples too.

Comment: @user2179021 In the example at the end, what is the significance of `(y0 or y1) or not z0`? This isn't equivalent to the solution, since it is true when y0=1 and y1=1. Did you mean `(y0 or y1) and not z0` where `z0 = y0 and y1`?

Comment: @Matt The logical formula can't contain an equals sign, it is just a logical formula.  I updated the example to actually relate to the example where we want the sum to be 1.

Comment: @user2179021 Whatever you mean by "to represent", I used "=" as shorthand. In any case, you modified your example to now say "then we can introduce a new clause `(y0 and not y1) or not z0` and replace `y0 and not y1` by `z0`". Then you are left with `z0 or not z0` which is tautologically true.

Comment: @Matt Let me check this as I may have made a silly mistake.  After substituting we have ((not y0 and y1) or z) and ((y0 and not y1) or not z) . If y0 = y1= False, for example, then this is (False or z) and (False or not z) which can't be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Write your desired sum in binary. First look at the least important bit, y0 . Clearly, 
x1 xor x2 xor ... xor xn = y0  - that's your first formula. The final formula will be a conjunction of formulae for each bit of the desired sum.

Now, do you know how an adder is implemented? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics) . Take inspiration from it, group your input into pairs/triples of bits, calculate the carry bits, and use them to make formulae for y1...yk . If you need further hints, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, you'll want to look into the general topics of *logic minimization* and/or *Boolean function simplification*.  The references are mostly about general methods for eliminating redundancy in Boolean formulas that are disjunctions ("or"s) of terms that are conjunctions ("and"s).

By hand, the standard method is called a Karnaugh map.  The equivalent algorithm expressed in a way that's more amenable to computer implementation is Quine-McKlosky (also called the method of prime implicants).  The minimization problem is NP-hard, and QM solves it exactly.

Therefore I think QM is what you want for the "super-optimizer" you're trying to build.

But the combination of NP-hard and exact solution means that QM is impractical for large problems, at least non-trivial ones.

The [QM Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) lays out the conjunctive terms (called minterms in this context) in a table and conducts searches for 1-bit differences between pairs of terms. These terms can be combined and the factor for the differing bit labeled "don't care" in further combinations. This is repeated with 2-bit, 4-bit, etc. subsets of bits.  The exponential behavior results because choices are involved for the combinations of larger bit sets: choosing one rules out another.  Therefore it is essentially a search problem.

There is an enormous literature on heuristics to trim the search space, yet find "good" solutions that aren't necessarily optimal.  A famous one is [Espresso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer). However, since algorithm improvements translate directly to dollars in semiconductor manufacture, it's entirely possible that the best are proprietary and closely held.